# What tools are needed for making 3D games?

Tags: tools

Hi I'm new to 3D games developing, I can a little c++, C#, VB.Net, 3D Max, ArchiCad ..etc. my problem is where to get started, which tools I need to start a own 3D game like GTA, I have tried some tools like : 'Unity3D' (crashes on start), '3D Rad' (uses only built-in items), 'Game Maker A7' (only 2D games can be made there).. could you help me to find the tools of making a 3D game..plz
I'm using Windows XP SP 2, I don't have pixel shader 1.1 into my video card

Comment: This is a really broad question and there isn't a specific problem to solve.  That being said fundamentally it's a dupe of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/351/pros-and-cons-of-various-3d-game-engines assuming that's the direction you end up going with.

Answer (score 3):

Go back and try Unity3D again.  It's a good product, and I'm sure with a bit of work you can figure out why it's crashing.

Comment: I've posted the problem already on Unity Comminutiy, they told me not to you Windows as the OS but an other one, Unity works sometimes fine and sometimes not on Windows, so they said to me.... I have now Unity3D Installed, but have problems with starting it..

Comment: @tim-holt your answer should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Unity 3d and Unreal Development Kit are the "best" options for making a 3d game, and are free to use.  Torque 3d is another option, but it's currently $99 for the non-demo version.  Other options are much more limited in what you can do, or are horribly expensive and probably not worth it if you're new to 3d development.

Other options are to make a mod of an existing game (saves you even more time, but can be even more limiting of what you can do), or to make your own engine (not a good idea if you're new to 3d, and rarely a great idea if you are experienced in 3d)

Comment: UDK would be fine, but my computer don't meet the minimum system requirements..
How can I make an own engine ? Thanks for help

Comment: I'd suggest making a mod for a game first, making a 3d game engine takes many people many years and is not a good place to start for a beginner.  If you have to make your own engine, then start learning directx or openGL.

Answer (score 1):

The best place you can start, given your description/knowledge base is **write mods**.  Use *an already existing game engine*/toolkit such as Aurora (Neverwinter Nights 2 engine) (for NWN type games) or Source engine (Half-Life 2 engine) for FPS type games.

Make sure you **play the games** thoroughly first, it will help you understand how the engine's level creator works.

Comment: can you tell me should I download those engines or how to go further, if download then plz provide a link, thanks a lot

Comment: You need to buy the games, and the editors come with them. You should preferably choose a game you already know you like.  If you're into Doom 3, [Dark Radiant](http://darkradiant.sourceforge.net/) may be good for you as well.